# Action sequence in Cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite, ccaction

I have an array of sprites. I want to loop through the array and tell each spirite to move a certain distance at a random angle, and fade out while doing so. Preferably with easing. Is there a way to set up a sequence to do this? Can you have a mutable sequence where you can add actions as you loop through the sprite array, and then run the sequence once you're done adding all the actions?

Comment: You may want to look into the Particle System functionality of cocos2d. It sort of sounds like you are trying to build something that may already exist.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand your question so well but maybe this example can help you:

```
CCArray *spritesArray; //array with sprites

float timeToMove = 1.0;
float timeToRotate = 1.0;
float timeToFadeOut = 1.0;
CGPoint initialMovePos = CGPointMake(100, 100);

for (int i = 0; i<[spritesArray count]; i++) {
    id moveDistance;
    if (i == 0) {
        moveDistance = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:timeToMove position:initialMovePos];
    }else{
        CGPoint lastSpritePos = ((CCSprite *)[spritesArray objectAtIndex:(i-1)]).position;
        moveDistance = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:timeToMove position:ccpAdd(lastSpritePos, CGPointMake(10, 10))];
    }

    float angleToRotate = random()%360;
    id rotateAction = [CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:timeToRotate angle:angleToRotate];
    id fadeOutAction = [CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:timeToFadeOut];

    CCSprite *sprite = [spritesArray objectAtIndex:i];

    [sprite runAction:[CCSpawn actions:moveDistance,rotateAction,fadeOutAction, nil]];
}
```